# Plot the random parts of the mixed effect output in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4, lattice

I have run a model by lmer

```
library(lmer)
mymodel<- glmer(wrimm ~ 1+itr+(1+itr|GE_state), data=dt_n, family = binomial(link="logit"),control=glmercontrol(optimizer="bobyqa"),nAGQ=0)
```

and use dotplot to visualise the random effect (including intercepts and slopes)

```
re<-ranef(mymodel, which="GE_state", conVar=TRUE)
lattice::dotplot(re, scales = list(x =list(relation = 'free')))
```

and acquire this figure

[image]

However, the dotplot has only limited functions for aesthetics. I would appreciate if someone can tell me how to make the same plot (a "forest plot", with random effect coefficients and their confidence intervals) by ggplot2.

Thank you for helping a beginner.

Comment: You may want to check out the `merTools` package. The finer points of getting confidence intervals for random effects models are described in a vignette as part of the package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/merTools/vignettes/Using_predictInterval.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example in this page shows how to plot in ggplot 2 as the output of lattice::dotplot:
https://rdrr.io/cran/lme4/man/ranef.html

```
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)

ranef(fm1)
str(rr1 <- ranef(fm1))

## as.data.frame() provides RE's and conditional standard deviations:
str(dd <- as.data.frame(rr1))
if (require(ggplot2)) {
    ggplot(dd, aes(y=grp,x=condval)) +
        geom_point() + facet_wrap(~term,scales="free_x") +
        geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=condval -2*condsd,
                           xmax=condval +2*condsd), height=0)
```

Comment: If you solved your own problem and waited long enough (I think the delay is 1 day), you can click on the check-mark to accept your own answer ...

Answer (score 0):

I think we need a bit more information on the data.frame produced with the random effects estimate from **ranef** and its layout, then it should be doable to

1. construct a dotplot in ggplot2 with geom_point() and errorbars with geom_errorbars() or geom_errorbarsh()
2. facet it by a variable to get one panel for each value of that variable